# Zend index searching with AND or OR condition not working

Tags: search, indexing, zend-framework, lucene

i have written an index searcher in Lucene that will search multiple fields in the indexed database.

i written following code.

```
public function actionInd(){
    $index = Lucene::open(Yii::$app->basePath."/search");
    $res = $index->find('name:pr AND id:2'); 
    foreach ($res as $hit){
        $document = $hit->getDocument();
        echo "<br>";echo "<br>";
        print_r($document->getFieldValue('id'));
        echo "<br>";
        print_r($document->getFieldValue('name'));
    }
}
public function actionCreate(){ 
$index = Lucene::open(Yii::$app->basePath."/search");
$doc = new Document();
$doc->addField(Field::Text('id', 3));
$doc->addField(Field::Text('name', 'pr'));
$doc->addField(Field::Text('title', 'prajapati'));
$doc->addField(Field::keyword('key', 3));
$index->addDocument($doc);
}
```

when call ind action output show:
1
pr
AND condition not working.

Comment: is it because you don't have documents with id:2 and name:pr?

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to give query is:

```
$query = Zend\Search\Lucene\Search\QueryParser::parse('name:pr AND id:2', 'iso-8859-5');
//or without char-encoding
$query = Zend\Search\Lucene\Search\QueryParser::parse('name:pr AND id:2');
$hits = $index->find($query);
```